# How to re-render children in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, render, higher-order-components

### Problem Context

I have a component named `<Layout/>` which contains my header and footer. It wraps all my routes as such:

```
<Layout>
    <div className="container">
        <Route path="/sign-in" exact component={SignIn}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={Home}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/statistics" exact component={Statistics}/>
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</Layout>
```

My `<Layout/>` component is defined as such:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
                {props.children}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I did this so that i don't have to include my header and footer in each and every component.

### Problem

In my header component, I am using the instance `auth` which indicates whether a user is logged in or not. The `auth` changes after the user signs in. However, even though the `auth` changes, my `<Header/>` component in the `<Layout/>` is not re-rendered. I have to manually refresh it to incorporate the changes. 
My `<Header/>` component is defined as:

```
import auth from '../../auth';

const Header = () => {
    return (
                {auth.isAuth() ? 
                    //render icon A
                : null
                }
                    <div>
                        Healthcare Management System      //header title
                    </div>
                {auth.isAuth() ? 
                    //render icon B
                : null
                }
            </div>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

This is my `auth` class:

```
class Auth{
    constructor(){
        this.authenticated = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('profile'));
    }
    login(cb){
        this.authenticated = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('profile'));
        cb();
    }
    logout(cb){
        this.authenticated = null;
        cb();
    }
    isAuth(){
        return this.authenticated;
    }
}
export default new Auth();
```

### What I require

What i want is supposedly simple; when the `auth.isAuth() == null`, show no icons and only the title (this behaves correctly). When, the `auth.isAuth() != null`, show icons A and B (this does not behave correctly and requires me to refresh the page in order to render the icons). 
Somehow, i want the `<Layout/>` component to re-render once the `auth changes`. Thank you!

Comment: That's not a HOC. You should pass auth as a prop or with useEffect

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Edited! I have tried passing the props from Layout to Header, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: What are "the props"? You'd need a callback to indicate an auth status change. That said, it might be better to use a context or other state management mechanism so the auth status can be trivially available throughout the app.

Comment: how do you set whether you are authenticated? Will the path changed when it is authenticated?

Comment: `authenticated` logic should be in the root component state and passed down via props. That, or use some state management tool for it. Personally, I would just use `RxJs` `BehaviorSubject` to hold the `authenticated` value and then extract it with `useObservable` hook from `react-use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React component is only rerendered when its props or its state is changing, therefore you should put auth in a state which can be set as followed:

```
import auth from '../../auth';

const Layout = (props) => {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if(!auth.isAuth()) {
          setAuthenticated(false);      
      } else {
          setAuthenticated(true);      
      }
    }, []);   // this useEffect logic is not working, you need to determine how you want to configure the condition in which authenticated state is set
    return (
        <div>
            <Header authenticated={authenticated} />
                {props.children}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Header component:

```
const Header = ({ authenticated }) => {
    return (
                {authenticated ? 
                    //render icon A
                : null
                }
                    <div>
                        Healthcare Management System      //header title
                    </div>
                {authenticated ? 
                    //render icon B
                : null
                }
            </div>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even console logged the `authenticated` state in the Layout component and it still just returns me the initially set state until i refresh.

Comment: I edited to show the auth file. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You mentioned "The auth changes after the user signs in", but I don't see this logic in your auth class, how do you set the session storage to indicate that the user has logged in?